# Can anyone know which language this is? And how do I connect this in NetBeans form?

Tags: xml, netbeans

Can anyone tell me which language this is and how I can connect this in my NetBeans project form? I can't figure out which language this actually is. I think it's HTML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Form version="1.5" maxVersion="1.9" type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JFrameFormInfo">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="defaultCloseOperation" type="int" value="2"/>
    <Property name="resizable" type="boolean" value="false"/>
  </Properties>
  <SyntheticProperties>
    <SyntheticProperty name="formSizePolicy" type="int" value="1"/>
    <SyntheticProperty name="generateCenter" type="boolean" value="true"/>
  </SyntheticProperties>
  <AuxValues>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoResourcing" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoSetComponentName" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateFQN" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateMnemonicsCode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_i18nAutoMode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_layoutCodeTarget" type="java.lang.Integer" value="1"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_listenerGenerationStyle" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesLocal" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesModifier" type="java.lang.Integer" value="2"/>
  </AuxValues>

  <Layout>
    <DimensionLayout dim="0">
      <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
          <Group type="102" alignment="1" attributes="0">
              <EmptySpace max="32767" attributes="0"/>
              <Component id="jLabel5" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <EmptySpace min="-2" pref="50" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <Component id="jLabel3" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <EmptySpace min="-2" pref="391" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
          </Group>
          <Group type="102" alignment="0" attributes="0">
              <EmptySpace min="-2" pref="29" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <Group type="103" groupAlignment="1" attributes="0">
                  <Component id="exitBtn" min="-2" pref="101" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                  <Component id="jScrollPane1" min="-2" pref="1293" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              </Group>
              <EmptySpace pref="31" max="32767" attributes="0"/>
          </Group>
      </Group>
    </DimensionLayout>
    <DimensionLayout dim="1">
      <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
          <Group type="102" attributes="0">
              <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
                  <Group type="102" attributes="0">
                      <EmptySpace min="-2" pref="99" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                      <Component id="jLabel3" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                  </Group>
                  <Group type="102" alignment="0" attributes="0">
                      <EmptySpace max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                      <Component id="jLabel5" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                  </Group>
              </Group>
              <EmptySpace min="-2" pref="27" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <Component id="jScrollPane1" min="-2" pref="306" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <EmptySpace type="unrelated" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <Component id="exitBtn" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
              <EmptySpace pref="119" max="32767" attributes="0"/>
          </Group>
      </Group>
    </DimensionLayout>
  </Layout>
  <SubComponents>
    <Component class="javax.swing.JLabel" name="jLabel5">
      <Properties>
        <Property name="icon" type="javax.swing.Icon" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.IconEditor">
          <Image iconType="3" name="/Forms/Iloilo_State_College_of_Fisheries.png"/>
        </Property>
      </Properties>
    </Component>
    <Component class="javax.swing.JLabel" name="jLabel3">
      <Properties>
        <Property name="font" type="java.awt.Font" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.FontEditor">
          <Font name="Calibri" size="18" style="1"/>
        </Property>
        <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" value="ISCOF VOTING MANAGEMENT SYSTEM"/>
      </Properties>
    </Component>
    <Container class="javax.swing.JScrollPane" name="jScrollPane1">
      <AuxValues>
        <AuxValue name="autoScrollPane" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true"/>
      </AuxValues>

      <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.support.JScrollPaneSupportLayout"/>
      <SubComponents>
        <Component class="javax.swing.JTable" name="resultsTable">
          <Properties>
            <Property name="model" type="javax.swing.table.TableModel" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.TableModelEditor">
              <Table columnCount="0" rowCount="4"/>
            </Property>
            <Property name="autoResizeMode" type="int" value="3"/>
            <Property name="columnModel" type="javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.TableColumnModelEditor">
              <TableColumnModel selectionModel="0"/>
            </Property>
            <Property name="cursor" type="java.awt.Cursor" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.CursorEditor">
              <Color id="Default Cursor"/>
            </Property>
            <Property name="fillsViewportHeight" type="boolean" value="true"/>
            <Property name="tableHeader" type="javax.swing.table.JTableHeader" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.JTableHeaderEditor">
              <TableHeader reorderingAllowed="false" resizingAllowed="false"/>
            </Property>
          </Properties>
        </Component>
      </SubComponents>
    </Container>
    <Component class="javax.swing.JButton" name="exitBtn">
      <Properties>
        <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" value="Exit"/>
      </Properties>
      <Events>
        <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="exitBtnActionPerformed"/>
      </Events>
    </Component>
  </SubComponents>
</Form>
```

Comment: This is `XML` and only needs the tag `XML`.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- It's Extensible Markup Language (XML).

Answer (score 1):

The language of the file itself is xml.  It says so in the first line.  But that in itself tells you very little, so you need to look further.

The second line of the file says this

```
<Form 
  version="1.5" 
  maxVersion="1.9" 
  type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JFrameFormInfo">
```

It's the type that helps you figure this out. It is the definition of an instance of Netbean's JFrameFormInfo class. You can almost certainly use this file in the netbeans IDE to define a form layout.